# How to use different ip address between virtual machine and your laptop?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ip-address

How to use different ip address between virtual machine and laptop. For laptop, my os is mac. And within my laptop, i run a virtual machine (vbox). The os within vbox is ubuntu 11. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your laptop and vbox should have difference ip address by default.

you can see more information to config virtual box networking mode from http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: but when i check my router configuration, both have same ip addr and mac addr.

Comment: yes NAT (default) mode using host's IP address. from your requirement you may consider to use Bridged mode.

Comment: how to change it? i am newbie :D Thank you

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVo_zFhGe3U

Comment: You need to use Bridge instead of Nat. So stop the virtual machines, then make the change in settings then reboot the vms and should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your VM's network configuration to bridged mode. It will then expose its generated MAC address to your network and get its own IP address from your router.